# Windows Server Cluster & Strange Day Light Savings Time Behaviour

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, cluster, time, daylight-saving

Over the weekend (Sunday March 27th) Daylight Savings Time kicked in here in Ireland and so all the servers (all win2k3 server) in our Production Environment updated their Times +1 Hour. However something which I cannot explain caused 2 of our cluster nodes to update @ 02:08 and 02:38 rather than @ 00:59.

We have 2 Domains in our production environment.

- DOMAIN1 contains PDC1 + 6 or 7 Virtual Machines. (Standalone Web, Load Bal, File servers)
- DOMAIN2 contains PDC2 + 2 Physical Servers which are clustered together for SQL Server

In DOMAIN1, everything seemed to work perfectly with all machines moving forward 1 hour at exacly `00:59:59` -> `02:00:00`. This can be confirmed by viewing timestamps in logfiles on any of those servers, or viewing timestamp data written to DB tables by those servers.

In DOMAIN2 however, something odd happened.

- Jobs in the SQL Server Agent Instance on DB_NODE_1 show the time change occuring @ 02:08. i.e. there are per minute jobs which show start times of 02:08, then 03:09
- Jobs in the SQL Server Agent Instance on DB_NODE_2 show the time change occuring @ 02:38. i.e. there are per minute jobs which show start times of 02:38, then 03:39

Same goes for DB Inserts on both instances that relied on the SQL `GetDate()` function. Data shows the getdate() inserts jumping forward +1 hour at `02:08` & `02:38` respectively on the two instances.

So my question is WHY?

All Servers (PDC, Physical & VM) have the exact same Locale & Timezone Settings (GMT, Ireland(English))
All Servers have the "Automatically Adjust for Daylight Savings Time" option selected.
All Non-PDC Servers are setup to use the Windows Time Service to get time updates from their PDC if there's any variances
All Servers have the exact same W32Time Registry Settings

So I am completely stumped why these 2 cluster nodes decided to wait 68 minutes & 98 minutes to do their DST updates.

Thanks if anyone can shine a light on this one.

Comment: Have you got anything configured for windows time service in group policy? What are the registry settings for a) your PDC and b) your non PDCs? The PDC EMulator DC and the other servers should not have the same w32time registry settings... the announcefalgs value should be different for one (probably 5 for you PDC em and 0 for other servers). Do you still have your windows event logs from back then? Were there any warnings/errors from w32time in your system log? Are all your servers up to date with the latest DST patches? (There have been several in recent years)

Answer (score 1):

The windows time service syncs up times in UTC, so that is not going to be your issue.

The only thing that comes to mind is that you have different sets of updates installed on some of the servers and they have different timezone data.  In general, you should use WSUS to ensure all the servers in a cluster of supposedly identical servers have the same updates applied.